# Traversing 2D array and showing the path taken

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to traverse a 2D array, first printing out a random array of 0s and 1s and then looping through that same array to change the 0s to 2s showing the path that is being taken to get from the top to the bottom. It compiles, but I can't quite figure out to get it to change the variables without forgetting about the random array. I tried using another set of for loops, which probably isn't the right way to do it...

Here is what I have come up with.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SearchMaze{    
    //Variables to set the values of the 2 arrays
    private static int n = 8;
    private static int m = 7;
    private static int[][] maze = new int[n][m];

    private static int i = 0;
    private static int j = 0;   

    public static void main(String [] args){    

    //Randomly select 0s and 1s for the array
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.print(n + "\t" + m);
    System.out.println("");

    //creates the random array of 0s and 1s
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
            maze[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2);

            System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
        }System.out.println("");
    }
    //here I was trying to loop through the array again while changing the 0s to 1s
    //to show if a "path" from the top to the bottom exists
    //but in doing this I am really just creating a different array of random 0s and 1s..   
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){

        maze[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2);

        while(i < n - 1 && j < m - 1){
        if(maze[i+1][j] == 0)
        {
            maze[i+1][j] = 2;
            i++;    
        }
        else if(maze[i-1][j] == 0)
        {
            maze[i-1][j] = 2;
            i++;
        }
        else if(maze[i][j+1] == 0)
        {
            maze[i][j+1] = 2;
            j++;
        }
        else if(maze[i][j-1] == 0)
        {
            maze[i][j-1] = 2;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            maze[i][j] = 1;
        }
        System.out.print(maze[i][j]);

    }System.out.println();
    }//end second for loop
}//end first for loop
}//end main method
}//end searchmaze
```

It will either change a few of the numbers at the bottom to 2s, just throw an error or generate an enormous amount of 1s without stopping.

Some of the errors I have come across...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at SearchMaze.main(SearchMaze.java:52)

Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at SearchMaze.main(SearchMaze.java:42)
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how your double-for loop accomplishes what you're trying to do (turn 0s to 2s?). If you're generating a large amount of 1s, it's probably because you're falling through to your `else maze[i][j] = 1;` case near the end of the file. You get an infinite loop because you don't change either `i` or `j`. Can you edit your post to include the exact error message that you're getting, and maybe some sample outputs?

Comment: @egracer added some of the errors I have come across, except for the infinite loop of 1s and 2s I get, for obvious reasons :P

Comment: What have you tried to do to debug? I'm still not clear on what exact problem you are asking for help. It looks like your posted errors happen because you're trying to get `maze[i-1][j]` and `maze[i][j-1]` when `i=0` and `j=0`, causing your out of bounds exception because arrays aren't indexed below 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SearchMaze{    
//Variables to set the values of the 2 arrays
private static int n = 8;
private static int m = 7;
private static int[][] maze = new int[n][m];

private static int i = 0;
private static int j = 0;

/*
* This function is used for searching a way from top to bottom exist or not.
*/
public static boolean searchMaze(int maze[][], int i, int j, int n, int m) {
    if(i == n-1 && j > 0 && j < m && maze[i][j] == 0) {
        // This is the condition when there is a way to the bottom.
        return true;
    } else if(i < 0 || i > m-1 || j < 0 || j > m-1 || maze[i][j] == 1) {
        // This is the condition when path is end in some where in middle.
        return false;
    } else {
        // There is three way to go bottom
        return searchMaze(maze, i+1, j-1, n, m) || searchMaze(maze, i+1, j, n, m) || searchMaze(maze, i+1, j+1, n, m);
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args){    

    //Randomly select 0s and 1s for the array
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.print(n + "\t" + m);
    System.out.println("");

    //creates the random array of 0s and 1s
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
            maze[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2);
            System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    //here I was trying to loop through the array again while changing the 0s to 1s
    //to show if a "path" from the top to the bottom exists
    //but in doing this I am really just creating a different array of random 0s and 1s..   
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
            // This is used to search a path from i,j to the bottom.
            if(searchMaze(maze, i, j, n, m)) {
                System.out.println("There is a way from "+i+" & "+j);
            }
        }//end second for loop
    }//end first for loop
}//end main method
}//end searchmaze
```